# Lambda value assignment with and without braces into @Composable function

Tags: kotlin, lambda, android-jetpack-compose

I'm following an Android Developers Codelab. I have this code fragment into a composable:

```kotlin
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = userGuess,
                singleLine = true,
                shape = shapes.large,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
                    focusedContainerColor = colorScheme.surface,
                    unfocusedContainerColor = colorScheme.surface,
                    disabledContainerColor = colorScheme.surface,
                ),
                onValueChange =  onUserGuessChanged ,
                label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.enter_your_word)) },
                isError = false,
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                    imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                ),
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                    onDone = { onKeyboardDone() }
                )
            )
```

onUserGuessChanged and onKeyBoardDone are both lambdas. This is the header of the Composable function

```
@Composable
fun myComposableFunction(
    onUserGuessChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    onKeyboardDone: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) { 
[...]
```

Why onValueChanged must be assigned without braces and function parenthesis, and onDone must be assigned with both?? What is the feature or difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin uses [Function Types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types), meaning that each function has a type and you can also assign functions to variables. Once we consider functions as types, we get an idea what might be necessary to directly assign a function to `onValueChange` or `onDone`:

The **function types** of [`onValueChange`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#OutlinedTextField(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material.TextFieldColors)) and the function that should be assigned to it **must match**.

```
onValueChange:      (String) -> Unit
onUserGuessChanged: (String) -> Unit
// MATCH
```

As the types match, we can assign function A to B like we would assign one variable to another.

Similarly, the **function types** of [`onDone`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/KeyboardActions#summary) and the function that should be assigned to it **must match**.

```
onDone:         (KeyboardActionScope.() -> Unit)?
onKeyboardDone: () -> Unit
// DOES NOT MATCH
```

These types do not match out of the box. We would need a function which is an extension to the `KeyboardActionScope` class.

The notation of a function type `A.(B) -> C` is called a [Function Literal with Receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver). We can only assign functions to such a type that either have the exact same type `A.(B) -> C` or `(A,B) -> C`. The `onKeyboardDone` function does not fulfill this criteria.

However, if we instead wrap the function call up in another lamdba, the lambda will **implicitly reflect the required type**. That's why with the lambda, it suddenly works.

If you managed to declare `onKeyboardDone` as a extension function of `KeyboardActionScope`, you could get rid of the additional lambda.

---

**Summary of Behavior**

[Variant A:](https://pl.kotl.in/Sy0XhpNt3)

```
val onKeyboardDone: () -> Unit = { System.out.println("Hello") }
val onDone: (String.() -> Unit)? = onKeyboardDone
```

> Compiler Error: Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Unit but (String.() -> Unit)? was expected

[Variant B:](https://pl.kotl.in/h54LdMiaG)

```
val onKeyboardDone: (() -> Unit) = { System.out.println("Hello") }
val onDone: (String.() -> Unit)? = { onKeyboardDone() }
```

> Compiler successful

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the explain. It has all the logic. But, why the onKeyboardDone() call don't works without the parenthesis in runtime?

Comment: From my understanding, you should already get an error at compile time when you don't use parenthesis. Are you able to compile the code without parenthesis?

Comment: Yes. When doing it, Android Studio highlights the call with the message: "expression is unused". But the programs compiles and launches right. On tapping Done over the keyboard nothing happens in this case.

Comment: That is surprising. See my edited answer, I added sample snippets on Kotlin playground. There, I already get a compiler error, if the types do not match exactly.